# python, number of arguments trouble

Tags: python, types, arguments

I have seen plenty of this question around, but I am still not able to see what I'm doing wrong.

I have several sliders, and I want the value of the one I am moving, and which of the slider is being moved.

to do that:

```
def reading(self,value):
    sender=self.sender()
    slider=sender.objectName()[6:]
    value_slider=value

    return slider, value_slider
```

That seems to work, the problem is with the next function.
Now, I want to do some stuff with the value of the slider moved:

```
def prsn(self,slider,value_slider):
    wv=np.linspace(380,780,401)
    leds=np.genfromtxt('led_psd.txt')
    leds_norm=leds/leds.max()
    Pot_ajust=0
    for i in range(0,leds_norm.shape[1]):
        Pot_ajust=Pot_ajust+value_slider*leds_norm[:,slider];
```

And I have the error : prsn() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

How come I am not "giving" to prsn() 3 arguments? It is like it is not reading value_slider and slider

How should I pass value_slider and slider to the other functions?

Thank you very much for any tip

Comment: Please show us where you call `prsn()`.

Comment: I'm guessing you're calling the function like so: `prsn()`. Your function is defined to accept arguments `slider,value_slider`. Pass `slider` and `value_slider` when calling: `prsn(slider, value_slider)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should call prsn:

```
s = stuff
vs = other_stuff
thingy.prsn(s,vs)
```

OR

```
thingy.prsn(slider=s,value_slider=vs)
```

This means that in prsn's scope:

```
self = thingy
slider = s
value_slider = vs
```

Please for now on when you ask a question include the line of code that causes the exception.